# Raspbian os Pi connected to ethernet but no network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, dns, ip, raspbian

im trying to connect to the internet and eventhough i conected the pi with a ethernet cable with a network enabled cable, it cant connect to the internet. another pi i have with the same cable is able to connect to the internet.

Pi with error

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:3a:dd:50:a7:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.107/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft 604532sec preferred_lft 604532sec
inet6 fe80::f802:4d3c:2b61:51fb/64 scope link noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

pi without error

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:3a:dd:23:88:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.124/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft 604014sec preferred_lft 528414sec
inet6 fe80::2ad3:8c00:79d6:97a1/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

the difference is that  the scope link for the pi with error has a noprefixroute flag to it. I did my research and believe it might be a dns issue but id love to get better advice on this.

Edit:
so you could not see in the question but there is a dongle. I have a huawei hilink dongle that is connected to both the pi. it just so happened that on the pi that has the problem, the hilink dongle was defaulted too by the pi and the hilink has its internet connection disabled. so by turning off the pi's ipv6 assigning by the hilink, i was able to remove it from the main connection ( this was a fluke i was playing around and i turned the ipv6 off for the hilink connection and suddenly the main connection from the cable works)so i guess if ur having the same issue you can try changing the advanced network settings on the raspian os

Comment: Can you share the ip routes `ip routes` There may be an default route which has no acces to internet

Comment: How did you test internet connection? Via e.g. ping (to IP, to domain...), curl, download?

Comment: Are you testing network access with IPv4 or IPv6? Please include your methodology in the question so we can, if necessary, attempt to try it ourselves locally. This is particularly important for what might be simply a DNS configuration issue

Comment: Are you really referring to Raspbian, or to raspberry pi OS? Two different things! The former is essentially a one-man maintained Debian derivative of a heroic maintainer with little to no support from the RPI foundation and 32 bit only, the other is the much younger RPi foundation's derivative of Ubuntu.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Is Raspberry Pi OS really based on Ubuntu? God I hope not.

Comment: Let me check that again, but I thought it was

Comment: @JaromandaX ah thankfully you're right, it's debian bookworm

Comment: FWIW, noprefixroute means adding an address doesn't automatically add a route. This hints that a networking tool was used and this networking tool will take care itself of the "missing" route. Also *both* Pi have this flag, so that's not a difference. Of course, we need the routes to have an opinion (`ip route` no trailing s).

Comment: @FelixJN i pinged google

Comment: @ChrisDavies hi , okay so you could not see in the question but there is a dongle. I have a huawei hilink dongle that is connected to both the pi. it just so happened that on the pi that has the problem, the hilink dongle was defaulted too by the pi and the hilink has its internet connection disabled. so by turning off the pi's ipv6 assigning by the hilink, i was able to remove it from the main connection ( this was a fluke i was playing around and i turned the ipv6 off for the hilink connection and suddenly the main connection from the cable works) .

Comment: @Yann you were right. so you could not see in the question but there is a dongle. I have a huawei hilink dongle that is connected to both the pi. it just so happened that on the pi that has the problem, the hilink dongle was defaulted too by the pi and the hilink has its internet connection disabled. so by turning off the pi's ipv6 assigning by the hilink, i was able to remove it from the main connection ( this was a fluke i was playing around and i turned the ipv6 off for the hilink connection and suddenly the main connection from the cable works)

Comment: Surya please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/759873/edit) to include the new information. Put everything in one place and it's easier for people to help you. (These comments can be deleted; your question will remain indefinitely.)

Comment: If your problem is solved, either delete your question or [answer yourself to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with how it was solved, but put an answer in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

so you could not see in the question but there is a dongle. I have a huawei hilink dongle that is connected to both the pi. it just so happened that on the pi that has the problem, the hilink dongle was defaulted too by the pi and the hilink has its internet connection disabled. so by turning off the pi's ipv6 assigning by the hilink, i was able to remove it from the main connection ( this was a fluke i was playing around and i turned the ipv6 off for the hilink connection and suddenly the main connection from the cable works)so i guess if ur having the same issue you can try changing the advanced network settings on the raspian os. ( this method somehow stopped working after a few days without any changes being made)

Method 2:

```
nmcli connection show
```

to show the connections,

```
sudo nmcli connection modify connection-name ipv4.route-metric 10
```

by adding the metric you will give it network priority on the pi

```
nmcli connection show connection-name
```

verify that the connection has changed in order.
The order of the networks shows the priority

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

to restart the network on your pi and it should work now.

( as of writing this it has been 1 day since I implemented this. i will update if it somehow reverts back or it works perfectly on in production)